# If statement is returning true when it should be false

Tags: c#, validation

I'm a student learning C# and this is my first post here.

I'm using a while loop with an if statement for validation and the if statement is returning true when it should be false after entering in the correct input.  My break points aren't telling me what is going on -- does anyone have any advice as to what I'm missing?

```
var genreSelection = Console.ReadLine();
bool invalidGenre = true;


while(invalidGenre == true)
{

    if (genreSelection != "SciFi" || genreSelection != "Fantasy" || genreSelection != "Horror" || genreSelection != "Action")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid selection, please choose either SciFi, Fantasy, Horror, or Action.");
        genreSelection = Console.ReadLine();

    }
    else
    {
        invalidGenre = false;
    }
}
```

Testing this loop I enter incorrect input initially, then I enter the correct input when prompted.  The if statement still fires rather than proceeding to the else and setting `invalidGenre` to false when I expect it to do otherwise.

Comment: I think you need && instead of || in your if

Comment: Tip: Utilize "[rubber duck debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" and read the expression out loud. Like "_genreSelection is not SciFi or genreSelection is not Fantasy..._", or like "_the animal is not a cat or the animal is not a dog..._". Of course the statement will always be true, because to turn it false you would need an _genreSelection_ string that is both "SciFi" and "Fantasty" at the same time, or an animal that is both [cat and dog at the same time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CatDog).

Answer (score 0):

You need a `&&` condition here and not `||`. You can streamline this using `System.Linq` `All()` methos like

```
if(new[] {"SciFi", "Fantasy", "Horror", "Action"}.All(x => x != genreSelection))
```